# Tengo un problema en JSF (Spring) para hacer persistir En el Bean de respaldo un <input type="file" />

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsf, java-8

Tengo un formulario en el que se incluye un   en una ventana de JSF.
Mi problema es que al hacer submit, todo persiste en ventana menos el    .

¿Como podria hace la persistencia de este componente en el Bean de respaldo de JSF?

Esta seria mi ventana.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/layout/template.xhtml">

         <h:form id="catalogacionForm" >

                 <h:outputScript target="body">

                 $(document ).ready(function() {
                      $("#fichero").change(function() {
                         var file = document.getElementById('fichero').files[0];
                         obtenerUrlTemporal([{name: 'nombreFichero', value:  file.name},{name: 'sizeFichero', value:  file.size}]);
                      });
                 });

                 function cargaTemporal(urlPresigned){

                     var fichero  = $('#fichero').prop("files")[0];
                     var formData = new FormData();
                     formData.append('file', fichero);
                     url = urlPresigned;

                     $.ajax({
                         url : url ,
                         type : 'PUT',
                         contentType : formData.type,

                         processData : false,

                         success : function(formData) {
                           console.log(formData);
                         },
                         error : function(formData) {
                           console.log(formData);
                         }
                     });
                 }
            </h:outputScript>

            <input type="file" name="fichero" id="fichero"
                required="true" />

            <p:remoteCommand name="obtenerUrlTemporal"
                immediate="true"

                action="#{respaldoBean.obtenerUrlTemporalBean()}"
                update="archivoCargado" />


            <h:inputText id="nombre" maxlength="250"
                value="#{respaldoBean.nombre}"
                required="true"
               >
            </h:inputText>


<p:remoteCommand value="submit"></p:remoteCommand>
         </h:form>

    </ui:composition>

</html>
```

Este seria el bean de respaldo

```
@Name("respaldoBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@ViewScoped
public class respaldoBean {

    private String nombre;

    public respaldoBean() {
        super();
    }


    /**
     * Método que genera una ruta temporal para almacenar el fichero
     * seleccionado.
     */
    public void obtenerUrlTemporalFica() {

           String url = "www.paginaPrueba.es?apkmej?";

            // Ejecutamos el script que cargara el fichero en la url temporal
            PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("cargaTemporal('"
                    + url + "')");
    }


    /**
     * @return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }


    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

Si solo selecciono el fichero de subida sin rellenar el campo nombre y pulso en submit. 
Lo que ocurre es que se muestra el mensaje de que el campo Nombre es requerido. pero el campo input se refresca y aparece como en la primera ejecucion.

Si relleno el campo nombre y pulso subimt. Este campo si que persiste y me muestra que es requerido el campo input type= file.

No se como hacer que el

¿Podeis ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="fichero" id="fichero"
            required="true" />
```

Esto es un tag HTML, no JSF. Aparece en la página, pero el JSF no lo procesa.

Ya que usas Primefaces, puedes usar el componente `<p:fileUpload>`, que sirve precisamente para eso (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml)

En todo caso, el nombre de una clase SIEMPRE debe empezar por mayúscula (RespaldoBean) y para cualquier scope persistente (como @ViewScoped) el bean debería implementar java.io.Serializable.